# LUA. io.read with time limit

Tags: asynchronous, input, lua

it is possible set time limit to read input in terminal in Lua.

For example you habe only 1 second to write a letter else program skip this action.

thanks for any tip ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by changing the terminal settings (see [`man termios`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios)) using [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) (on POSIX machines only, obviously):

```
local p = require( "posix" )

local function table_copy( t )
  local copy = {}
  for k,v in pairs( t ) do
    if type( v ) == "table" then
      copy[ k ] = table_copy( v )
    else
      copy[ k ] = v
    end
  end
  return copy
end

assert( p.isatty( p.STDIN_FILENO ), "stdin not a terminal" )

-- derive modified terminal settings from current settings
local saved_tcattr = assert( p.tcgetattr( p.STDIN_FILENO ) )
local raw_tcattr = table_copy( saved_tcattr )
raw_tcattr.lflag = bit32.band( raw_tcattr.lflag, bit32.bnot( p.ICANON ) )
raw_tcattr.cc[ p.VMIN ] = 0
raw_tcattr.cc[ p.VTIME ] = 10 -- in tenth of a second

-- restore terminal settings in case of unexpected error
local guard = setmetatable( {}, { __gc = function()
  p.tcsetattr( p.STDIN_FILENO, p.TCSANOW, saved_tcattr )
end } )

local function read1sec()
  assert( p.tcsetattr( p.STDIN_FILENO, p.TCSANOW, raw_tcattr ) )
  local c = io.read( 1 )
  assert( p.tcsetattr( p.STDIN_FILENO, p.TCSANOW, saved_tcattr ) )
  return c
end

local c = read1sec()
print( "key pressed:", c )
```

Answer (score 0):

The lcurses (ncurses for Lua) Lua library might provide this. You would have to download and install it. There is an example of how to check for keypress only at [Create a function to check for key press in unix using ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025891/create-a-function-to-check-for-key-press-in-unix-using-ncurses), it is in C but the ncurses API is identical in Lua.

Otherwise, you will have to create a Lua extension module using the C/C++ API: you would create C function that you call from Lua, and this C function then has access to the OS's usual function like getch, select, etc (depends if you are on Windows or Linux).