# Configure key repeat delay to detect if key is being pressed

Tags: c, terminal, key, delay, curses

I am writing a program in C that uses ncurses to check if a key is being pressed. The problem is that there is a key repeat delay.

If I for example hold the key 'a' while in the terminal there is a short delay before 'a' gets repeatedly entered. I want to be able to know if it is being pressed from the point where it is actually pressed.

How do temporarily change this delay to be equal to 0 while in the terminal? I'm currently using Mac OSX 10.10.5.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but that does unfortunately not fix my problem. The problem cannot be solved with ncurses, it is caused by the terminal itself.

Comment: Setting the delay for key-repeat is not really related to detecting a key press (unless you have omitted some information from your question).  See [this page](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/how-to-increase-keyboard-key-repeat-rate-on-os-x) for OSX key-repeat rate.

Comment: The only way to detect input as far as I'm aware is using getchar(). If I currently press and hold 'a' getchar() will read the input:
'a', '?', '?', '?', 'a', 'a', 'a', ...
(Where '?' is no input at all which happens because of the key repeat delay), I want getchar() to read the input this instead:
'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', ...

If there however is some way to detect key releases, please let me know as it would also be a valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

With ncurses (any curses implementation), you would use [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) rather than [`getchar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getchar.3.html).  The latter is a C standard I/O input function.

Someone suggested *[Create a function to check for key press in unix using ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025891/create-a-function-to-check-for-key-press-in-unix-using-ncurses)*, which contains an answer worth mentioning.  It uses [`nodelay`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay) to eliminate the time normally spent in `getch` for successive bytes of an escape sequence.  In curses, you always have a tradeoff between waiting or not, since an escape sequence may not arrive all in one `read` operation.  The example shown there reports cases when no character is available, and pauses (sleeps) for a short time in that case.

If you only want to see the characters which are read, you could eliminate that pause (but making your program use a lot of CPU time):

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int kbhit(void)
{
    int ch = getch();

    if (ch != ERR) {
        ungetch(ch);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    initscr();

    cbreak();
    noecho();
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);

    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    while (1) {
        if (kbhit()) {
            printw("Key pressed! It was: %d\n", getch());
        }
    }
}
```

or (recognizing that there is a tradeoff), use [`napms`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-napms) to pause a *short* amount of time, but lessening the CPU time used:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int kbhit(void)
{
    int ch = getch();

    if (ch != ERR) {
        ungetch(ch);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    initscr();

    cbreak();
    noecho();
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);

    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    while (1) {
        if (kbhit()) {
            printw("Key pressed! It was: %d\n", getch());
        } else {
            napms(20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code. Sorry if I was not clear enough, what I need is a way for the system to know if a key is being held down. It would also be useful to know if a key is being released. So basically I need a way to check for "KEYDOWN" and "KEYUP" events.

Comment: You should state these details in your question when you first ask it.  I believe I addressed all of the points in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to ignore buffered key repeats:

```
int key;
if ((key = getch()) != ERR) {
  while (getch() == key);
}
```

In context:

```
//example.c

#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int pos_x = 0;
  int max_x = 0, max_y = 0;
  int key = 0;
  int on = 1;

  initscr();
  noecho();
  cbreak();
  curs_set(FALSE);
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
  getmaxyx(stdscr,max_y,max_x);

  while(1) {
    clear();
    mvprintw(0, 0, "Press, hold and release L-R arrow keys. Press UP/DOWN to toggle function.");
    mvprintw(1, 0, "Skip buffered repeats: %s", (on ? "ON" : "OFF"));
    mvprintw(2, pos_x, "@");
    refresh();
    usleep(50000);
    getmaxyx(stdscr,max_y,max_x);
    key = getch();

    // skip buffered repeats                                                                                     
    if (on) {
      if (key != ERR) {
        while (getch() == key);
      }
    }
    //                                                                                                           

    switch (key) {
    case KEY_LEFT:
      pos_x += (pos_x > 0 ? -1 : 0); break;
    case KEY_RIGHT:
      pos_x += (pos_x < max_x - 1 ? 1 : 0); break;
    case KEY_UP:
      on = 1; break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
      on = 0; break;
    }
  }
  endwin();
}
```

Compile and run with `gcc example.c -lncurses -oexample && ./example`