# Function of _kbhit()

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at C++ and trying to code a  C++ console based snake game. I was stuck when I cannot move the snake without continuously pressing a key. Now I can do by just pressing the key once but I still do not understand the function of _kbhit() which has helped me do it.

```
void snake_movement(){
    if(_kbhit())
    switch (getch())
    {
    case 'w':
        y_cordinate--;
        break;
    case 'a':
        x_cordinate--;
        break;
    case 's':
        y_cordinate++;
        break;    
    case 'd':
        x_cordinate++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: yeah sorry i have changed it

Comment: @ Dialecticus that what this _kbhit() does here precisely?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346261/configure-key-repeat-delay-to-detect-if-key-is-being-pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_getch()` is a blocking function. If no keypresses are available in the input buffer, it will wait for a keypress to become available in the input buffer. So your program gets stuck inside of `_getch()` until a key is pressed - and that's why it wouldn't "work" unless you keep the key pressed, so that `_getch()` can keep returning to your program. It still would get "stuck", because new keystrokes are only available at the key repeat rate. That is: in the best case, `_getch()` may return a few dozen times per second. But only if a key is pressed down, and if the operating system supports autorepeat for that key.

On the other hand, `_kbhit()` doesn't block. It returns immediately with a zero value if no keypress is available in the input buffer. Otherwise it returns a non-zero value. That indicates that a key is available, and that you can call `_getch()` to get it. `_kbhit()` returning non-zero guarantees that `_getch()` won't block, i.e. it won't wait but will return immediately with the result you need.